# Animating element using jQuery and calling stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

In my navigation I have elements that get higher when the mouse is hovering them. When rapidly moving mouse in and out of the element it causes problems. I searched the web and found somekind of solution, the jQuery `stop` method. I tried that, but didn't get it quite working.

When you slowly move your mouse over the `li` element and out, it works just fine (the animations get to finnish) but when you move your mouse faster it fails.

[Here's the codes and the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/HAdPQ/)

What might be wrong?

What about if I want to keep the text 10 px from the bottom? How do I implement that?

Comment: The main problem with the example is not the stop, but the relative heights! If you quickly hover over different elements, some animate to height 0.

Answer (score 2):

[stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) take two arguments.

- A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation
- A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately

You need to add this 2 arguments to make it work as expected:

```
$(element).stop(true, true).animate({.....
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HAdPQ/1/)

Comment: Well that works but is there something you can do to the flickering?

Comment: +1 but I am also looking for flick free - trying to work on the same

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery hoverintent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

```
$("nav").hoverIntent( makeTall, makeShort, 'li' )
```

Where `makeTall` and `makeShort` are your functions to handle the CSS.